# How Could A Diffie Hellman Key Exchange Work on SMS Apps on Two Different Mobile Devices?

Tags: mobile, android, diffie-hellman, sms

How Could A Diffie Hellman Key Exchange Work on SMS Android Apps on Two Different Mobile Devices? It is understandable for a client browser communicating with a server, the internet data path is continous unlike SMS that is relayed via GSM network.

Comment: your presumption, "the internet data path is continuous", is wrong, by the way. The internet works based on packets, and the fact that you can have a "stream" of data is just higher-level construction and interpretation of these packets

Comment: Yes, but I think the real question is why? What would be the reason for using a provenly compromised key exchange technique to develop a more complicated system for data transfer rather than just using an established and mission tested zero knowledge system. Examples include things such as openpgp. New asymmetric algorithms like ECC also show promise.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible . Why not?

Diffie-Hellman only demands you exchange data. There's no restriction on how that data gets from A to B. You might use the internet, SMS, carrier pigeons, shout it across the marketplace, morse it, use sky beamers to write it into the night sky…

How you encode the couple of bits into SMS, letters attached to carrier pigeons, buzzwords shouted across the market place, letters morsed, or sky beamer figures is up to you. In the end, Diffie-Hellman just requires you to send a few numbers around.